# The Equivalent Term for Pharmacy in the UK

Tags: vocabulary, british-english

In the States, we use the term "pharmacy" or "drugstore," but what is the equivalent in the UK? I checked two sources, but came up with nothing.

Comment: Where all have you looked? Just curious, say. (I came in late, the down vote is bad enough, but this comment ought not to hurt the OP, this one's in good faith, sure.)

Comment: Two not so useful, unfortunately, online sites. One said "drugstore" but I thought it was something other than that. Cheers.

Comment: In the future, try looking for something along the lines of "American vs. British English".

Comment: "*you may think it's a long way down the street to the chemist, but that's just peanuts to space.*" --Douglas Adams, THHGttG

Comment: They always use "chemist" on those BBC detective shows.

Comment: Please reconsider the accepted answer, I can confirm from direct experience that "drugstore" would sound extremely unnatural to my British ears and I have never once heard it used in any area of England. However chemist's and pharmacy are both in common use, a nuance would be that a chemist's is almost always a standalone shop where a medicine counter in a larger shop would almost always be called a pharmacy.

Comment: In the 19th century there was a difference between a *pharmacy* and a *chemist and druggist's shop*.  The later term became shortened to a *chemist's*, often with a pharmacy counter within it.  [Sir Richard Robinson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Robinson_%28Municipal_Reform_politician%29) was an example of a chemist and druggist who owned pharmacies and employed pharmacists

Comment: The accepted answer says **chemist's** which is correct. It does not say that Brits use the term *drugstore* as a synonym, it says that the term is not as "foreign" as it once was (starting to creep into standard UK usage). Britons may *not* say it, and chemist shops may still not be called *drugstores* but the term isn't exactly weird. Do Brits balk at *candy* and *cookies* nowadays? Not any more.

Comment: @user1873 Douglas Adams is of course quoting from an *intergalactic* source, so it could hardly tell us much about anything as parochial as UK/US dialectic differences.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's *a chemist's*, though *drugstore* is starting to creep into standard UK usage too.

Comment: I've never heard "drugstore" in British English. "Pharmacy" sounds like a much more natural alternative to me.

Comment: Agree with @DavidRicherby. _Pharmacy_ is the term which has been coming in.

Comment: @ColinFine   There's a chain of pharmacies (think Boots) in the UK called [Superdrug](http://www.superdrug.com/Health/c/health) so it's safe to say that the term *drugstore* has already crept into the UK. EDIT: Just seen D.Richerby's post

Comment: @Mari-LouA That's a bit of a leap - you could equally use that argument say that _druggist_ has crept in.  I've rarely heard either.

Comment: @Deditos no, I don't think so. *Superdrug* is a chain of shops, and British speakers are familiar with the term store, (not too much of a leap there) there's also American TV series, films, DVDs, books etc. to take into consideration. The UK may be an island but it's not isolated from the USA or the rest of the world.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Sure, I see how the link is made, and US words enter UK English all the time, but in this case I haven't seen it's usage.  British newspapers for instance tend to use drugstore to refer to US companies and chemist/pharmacy to refer to UK ones, e.g., http://www.thesundaytimes.co.uk/sto/business/Companies/article1411859.ece

Comment: @Deditos  I'm pretty certain that thirty or forty years ago the term *drugs* was normally reserved for "narcotics" in the UK, it was nearly always "medicine". Nowadays British people are familiar with  *drugs* being synonymous with medicine/medications/prescriptions. So maybe there aren't actual chemist's called "drug stores" in the UK but that doesn't mean the term is unheard of.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Sure, it would be logical for British people to use "drugstore" and the term would probably be understood.  But, in my experience (native speaker, lived in the UK for 35 of my 37 years), the term simply is not used in the UK.

Comment: In the UK 'Drugs' are narcotics and would only be understood as medicines if explicitly stated. The term 'Drugstore' would not be used, but like most American terms (faucet etc.) would be understood when used by an American. A British person using these terms would probably be made fun of.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: I don't think anybody's suggesting that we don't understand the word _drugstore_ in the UK. But several of us are saying that we, and Brits in general, don't use it.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - Superdrug is referred to as the brandname for that specific chain.  Drugstore is one of those 'americanisms' which is actively rejected (like cell-phone and 'pants' to refer to trousers.)

Comment: @DavidRicherby Google ngram [seems to agree with you](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=chemist%2Cpharmacy%2Cdrugstore&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cchemist%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpharmacy%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdrugstore%3B%2Cc0). While `chemist` is the predominant term, `pharmacy` is gaining ground, whereas `drugstore` really isn't.

Comment: @ThomasH limit the search between 1950 and 2008; add the apostrophe to chemist and you get a very different picture for [chemist's, pharmacy and drugstore](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=chemist%27s%2Cpharmacy%2Cdrugstore&year_start=1950&year_end=2008&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cchemist%20%27s%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpharmacy%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdrugstore%3B%2Cc0) Remember that a chemist is also an expert, an occupation so the results will be skewed. (hit *search lots of books* in order to see results)

Comment: This answer is nonsense.  I live in the UK and the most common word to use is "pharmacy".  I've never heard it described as a "drugstore".

Comment: Upon what basis do you claim that "drugstore is starting to creep into standard UK usage too"? Your profile says your location is the United States. As a UK resident "drugstore" sounds very American to me.

Comment: @Mari-LouA click through and [look at the actual books the term appears in](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22drugstore%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:2001,cd_max:2008&lr=lang_en). They are all American despite doing the search using British English.

Comment: I'm another English person who lives in England, a country in Britain. I've never heard a British person in Britain use the term "Drug Store." When I visit the Chemist, the Pharmacy in the Chemist or Supermarket, or the shop that some people call a Pharmacy I sometimes talk to the Pharmacist. I may ask the Pharmacist to satisfy my Doctor's prescription or recommend some medicine for my ails. I would not ask him for drugs. If I asked for drugs in the street drugs I may be directed to a Police Officer.

Comment: @Mari-Lou In most places in Britain if you asked for a *drugstore* and didn't have an American accent, they would look at you a bit strangely. The point is that in Britain we do not use the term *narcotics* so *drugs* are the nasty, illegal things. Asking for a *drugstore* in Britain would be a bit like, in America, asking someone in the street where you could get a fix.

Comment: @WS2 sigh...  The answer clearly states *chemist's*, the OP didn't say everyone in the UK uses the term *drugstore*, he suggested that it is creeping into usage. British people are travellers, they own TVs, they go to the cinema, a word like *drugstore* is about foreign-sounding as "cookie" or "truck" or "pants" or "OJ" (orange juice in case you didn't know), so people have heard it. The term is known, it is heard in the UK.

Comment: No one under the age of 40 will think a drugstore sells drugs (BrEng)  or narcotics (e.g. cocaine, heroin, cannabis). I am convinced of this. I had a British boyfriend in Italy for nearly seven years, and we visited the UK very often.

Comment: I am astonished that such an incorrect answer can be allowed to stand. From the comments which have been made it is quite clear that the word *drugstore* is not part of any British lexicon and shows no signs whatever of so becoming.

Comment: @Mari-LouA But it patently is not 'creeping in' to use in Britain. As someone has pointed out it is one of those Americanisms which is actively resisted in Britain. And that for the simple reason that 'drugs' are narcotics. People do not talk about giving drugs. Doctors tend not to use the term unless they are speaking about illegal substances. They either say *medication* or *pills* or something.

Comment: @WS2 the post has 12 downvotes, it was posted over a year. It has **chemist's** Let it go. Would you believe me if I said I didn't upvote or downvoted it? I just left a comment and everyone charged at me and at poor Eric who kept schtum all through.

Comment: @Mari-LouA as long as you and Eric understand that the word ***drugstore*** has no currency whatever in Britain.

Answer (score 54):

*Chemist*, *chemist's*, *chemist's shop* or, sometimes, *pharmacy*. I've never heard "drugstore" in the UK, though one of the big chains is called Superdrug.

Comment: Two of the largest UK chains that I know of contain the word *pharmacy*, ABC Pharmacy and Boots Pharmacy. *Pharmacy* is fully understood and recognised here, and in my view it's become more prominent than *chemist* mainly thanks to Boots.

Comment: @user Um. Boots refer to themselves as *Boots the Chemist*, though they do use the word "pharmacy" to describe the parts of their business that sell medicines. And, as far as I can see, ABC actually refer to themselves as *ABC Drugstore* (!) but they're far from being one of the largest UK chains: they only have a few shops, all of which are in London. They don't even seem to have a website!

Comment: Aha! The answer underneath this holds the key to my confusion - chemists contain pharmacies. The chemists around my area all have pharmacy on a big sign with or next to the name. Today's fact has been learnt! :)

Comment: Chemist is still the de facto name. Pharmacy would be widely understood, Drugstore would usually be understood, but neither would often be used by a native speaker

Comment: Definitely not the "House Of Fun" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GJ2X9SANsME

Answer (score 19):

Technically a *chemist's* [shop] will contain a *pharmacy*, which is the counter where prescription drugs can be obtained.  Because it may be necessary to get these when shops are closed, there is a rota (published in the local paper, for example) of out-of-hours pharmacies; some of these are in supermarkets or 24-hour shops.

Answer (score 9):

I think that the answer to this has changed over the last thirty years or so. When I was a kid, *chemist's* was invariably the term I heard, though *pharmacy* wouldn't have been incorrect. But recently, I don't think I've heard anyone say *chemist's*: it's always been *pharmacy*.

I've never heard a Brit say *drugstore*. Although we have a chain called *Superdrug*, I distinctly recall thinking the name was weird and slightly creepy when I first encountered it. I still do when I think about it, though of course one gets used to the anomaly.

I can't say how localised or typical this experience is. I'm from middle class southern Britain, but your kilometerage might vary.

Comment: I agree that ***pharmacy*** is now a widely accepted term in Britain, though people still say *would you be kind enough to pop into the chemists for me please*. Particularly in supermarkets they refer to ***the pharmacy counter***. The problem with the use of  ***drugstore*** in Britain, is that ***drugs*** are nasty illegal substances, which Americans call ***narcotics*** - but we seldom do.

Answer (score 1):

The most common (and one that would be understood by 99.9% of people living in the UK), will call it a **pharmacy**.

Although, you'd get away with calling it a **chemist**.

---

People mentioning 'Boots' or 'superdrug' should note that that is a full *shop*, not just a **pharmacy** or **chemist**.

~Source Me *(as an Englishman)*

---

In order to clarify the terms *chemist* and *pharmacy* (although in the UK, people might/will interpret these differently (apparently)), i have included a 'comparison' for you:

*A chemist is a scientist who develops drugs, and a pharmacy is a store that sells drugs. However, in Britain the word chemist is commonly used to denote a pharmacy*

Comment: This appears to be exactly the wrong way around. For example, Boots refers to itself as "Boots the Chemist" and their shops, which sell snacks, cosmetics, hair care products and all kinds of other things, contain a pharmacy counter.

Comment: I'm pretty sure locally it's known as 'Boots', plus one of my parents is a **Pharmacist**. Boots is a *shop* which contains a *chemist*.

Comment: Just google it, its "Boots the Chemist" especially for older generations. https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Boots+the+Chemist&oq=Boots+the+Chemist&aqs=chrome..69i57.8864j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8

Comment: To be honest, I believe you to be 'spitting hairs' over whether boots is a chemist/pharmacy/shop/whatever. I'm saying that, in light of the question, it's either a 'pharmacy' or 'chemist'. i've never heard of 'Boots the Chemist', but i've heard of 'Boots' (as do the people working there). Plus, even if they did, this is just says their point of view. There's HUNDREDS of other 'drugstores', each of them selling very similar products, of whom call themselves differently. Secondly, Boots USED to be called a 'chemist', but have since changed their name after expansion.

Comment: @Jodrell: *A chemist is a scientist who develops drugs, and a pharmacy is a store that sells drugs. However, in Britain the word chemist is commonly used to denote a pharmacy.*

Comment: @Jodrell: Please read the definitions above. We're talking about a 'UK persons' interpretation of 'drugstore', and what they would call a 'drugstore'.

Comment: In sum: "Chemist", the British term for pharmacist, or its possessed form "chemist's", applies in popular (if not in corporate branding) usage to the entire shop, much of which contains goods irrelevant to health care, while in the U.S. "drugstore" has this broader denotation. In both contexts, however, the term "pharmacy" refers quite narrowly to the chemist's/pharmacist's specialized domain. This explains the otherwise paradoxical sign on the door of my local CVS Pharmacy listing different hours of operation for the "Pharmacy" (where prescriptions are filled) and the (rest of) the "Store".