# Which one of these is the most commonly used in English?

Tags: meaning

-Which one of these is the most commonly used in English?

> 1. Chemist, or Chemist's
> 2. Pharmacist, or Pharmacy
> 3. Druggist, or Drugstore

Comment: In BrE it's normally *[the] chemist's*. That's somewhere you can buy other stuff besides prescription drugs. A *pharmacy* is normally only used in the specific sense of "supplier of prescription drugs", so you might find one of those *within* a hospital, for example (but they won't sell you beauty products, etc.). Maybe Americans have *druggists* as well as *drug stores* (that's where they used to buy/drink stuff like soda pops in 50s movies, but maybe I'm a bit out of date on that one).

Comment: Drug stores in the US still sell other sundry items (including canned and bottled pop ) and includes a "pharmacy counter" where prescription drugs are purchased.  However, the soda fountain is sadly, no longer a part of the typical drugstore.

Comment: This question has already been answered [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/212219/the-equivalent-term-for-pharmacy-in-the-uk/212238#212238)

Comment: Where??  It differs depending on where you live.

Comment: @FF Or perhaps _[the] chemists_.  From [Expatica](http://www.expatica.com/uk/healthcare/healthcare/UK-healthcare-Guide-to-NHS-services_103168.html) : _Remember to take ID with you to the chemists_.

Answer (score 2):

In Britain the word ***drugs*** almost always refers to illegal substances. Britain does not use the word ***narcotics***.

For that reason there is active resistance to calling pharmacies (also known as chemists) *drugstores*.

Anyone asking in the street for the nearest ***drugstore***, if they didn't have an American accent, would be looked at rather strangely.

Whilst people always used to talk of ***the chemist's***, the words ***pharmacy*** and ***pharmaceuticals*** have become far more widely used in Britain in recent decades. This is particularly the case in supermarkets who nearly always refer to their ***pharmacy counter***.

Answer (score 1):

In American English, it is **pharmacist** (requiring two years of undergraduate university study plus completion of a four-year Doctor of Pharmacy program, as well as passing the North American Pharmacist Licensure Examination administered by the National Association of Boards of Pharmacy (NABP), and obtaining a state license, e. g., for California or New York). Where they work is called a **pharmacy**.

http://study.com/articles/Pharmacist_Educational_Requirements_and_Career_Summary.html

A search for "pharmacies" in my relatively small city (population less than 50,000) returns about ten pharmacies, all of which either sell sundries as well, or are **departments** in much larger chain stores that sell up to tens of thousands of other, non-pharmaceutical items. Locally, these include Safeway (primarily groceries), Costco, WalMart, Target, CVS, Walgreen's, Rite Aid, and two privately owned pharmacies.